# I can't figure out why this Recursion isn't working

Tags: java, oop, recursion, input

I am learning about Recursions, and I haven't fully grasped it yet. So here I am trying to do an assignment on recursion but I'm stuck.

In this assignment, I am supposed to ask the user to input phrases, and the program determines whether it's a palindrome or not. We are supposed to accomplish this task using recursions.

This is the section with the recursion, and I can't quite figure out how to tackle it, as when I run it, I get no error, but it always comes up as false.

I'm using a `ArrayList` to keep all the user input.

Here's the code I've got right now

```
//instance variables
private boolean det;
private String input;
private String inputHelp;

//constructor
public RecursivePalindrome(String i)
{
    det = false;
    input = i;
    inputHelp = "";
}

//determines if the method is a palindrome or not using recursions
public boolean palindrome(String b)
{

    if(inputHelp.length() == 0)
    {
        det = true;
    }
    if(inputHelp.substring( 0 , 1 ).equals(inputHelp.substring( inputHelp.length() )))
    {
        inputHelp = inputHelp.substring( 1, inputHelp.length());
        palindrome(inputHelp);
    }
    else 
    {
        det = false;
    }
    return det;
}
```

Comment: Recursive methods usually shouldn't use global or instance variables to do their work, at least until you understand recursion better.  When a method calls itself, and the second call modifies a global or instance variable, it affects how the first call will work in ways you probably don't intend.  Simple recursive methods (like the kind you see in classroom settings) should probably use only their arguments and local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three mistakes. First, note the [`substring` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29): second parameter is the end index "exlusive". Secondly, you need to use the result of the recursive call. And finally (as pointed out correctly by [ajb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464386/ajb) in the comments), you should account for palindromes with odd letter count (first condition):

```
if (inputHelp.length() <= 1)
{
    det = true;
}
else if (inputHelp.substring(0, 1)
             .equals(inputHelp.substring(inputHelp.length() - 1)))
{
    inputHelp = inputHelp.substring( 1, inputHelp.length() - 1);
    det = palindrome(inputHelp);
}
else 
{
    det = false;
}
```

Also, you can make it a bit more readable:

```
public boolean palindrome(String b)
{
    if (b.length() <= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (b.substring(0, 1)
           .equals(b.substring(b.length() - 1)))
    {
        return palindrome(b.substring(1, b.length() - 1));
    }

    return false;
}
```

Further improvements can be made - lines still seem to long, especially the second condition (left as an exercise for the reader ;)).

Comment: This solution (the second one) is totally wrong.  But maybe it's an appropriate solution for StackOverflow, because that's exactly what your code will do.

Comment: OK, one problem fixed.  Still fails if the original string is a palindrome with an odd length.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for your comment (even though this code didn't produce stack overflow "exactly" as you claim :)). Good call on odd length - fixed this also.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are never setting `inputHelp` to anything other than an empty string, and the string `b` which is passed in to your method is not used anywhere.

So the method will never call back on to itself, and even if it did the value passed in would not be used for anything, rendering the recursion useless.